# Quit after running Microsoft Access as a Scheduled Task

Tags: ms-access, vba, taskmanager

I have set Windows Task Manager to run macro on MS Access in a time interval (15 mins)

I run the macro by setting Task Manager not by the VBA. And the macro runs both my VBA code and batch file for WinSCP!

I want it to close the Access program upon starting the macro. (Hopefully not in a second.. as my WinSCP runs for a second to complete import 100% )

Is there anyway that I can set it as I want?

> What is not working : Automatically close the Access program upon
>   starting it to trigger macro to run by Windows Task Manager
>
> What's working: Task Manager automatically starts my Access program

Comment: Please elaborate, what is NOT working and what is working

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the top of your code module:

```
#If VBA7 Then
  Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
  Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
```

To quit Access after one second, call this sub:

```
Sub CloseAccess()
 Dim i As Integer

 For i = 1 To 10
  Sleep 100
  DoEvents
 Next i
 DoCmd.Quit
End Sub
```